# HTML/JS: Alternatives to Datalist that shows all options (no autocomplete)

Tags: javascript, html, search, autosuggest, html-datalist

i'm still a total web dev noob. Currently i am working on a searchbar for my website. Right now I attached a datalist to my search input as a way to show suggestions. Javascript dynamically adds options to the datalist based on the results of my search algorithm (onKeyUp).
But I want to display all options, not just the autocompleted options of the whole set of options.
I like the datalist because it just works instantly without having to modify my CSS.
Is there some way of accomplishing that task using something as simple as a datalist or is there some workaround i didn't find?
The ones i did find, didn't seem to work for me.

I would appreciate some help a lot.

Edit:
HTML:

```
   <input type="search" list="dataList" onkeyup="onKeyUp(this.value)"  placeholder="search...">
    <datalist id="dataList"></datalist>
```

JS:

```
function onKeyup(text){
     const dataList = document.getElementbById('dataList');
    
     // this contains the strings i want to display in my dataList
     // you can imagine it as ["apple", "orange", "banana"]
     // I want to display all of those elements, no matter what text was entered
     let myArr = mySearchAlgorithm(text);
     dataList.innerHTML = "";
     myArr.forEach(string => {
         console.log(string);
         const option = document.createElement('option');
         option.setAttribute('value', string);
         dataList.appendChild(option);
    });
}
```

Comment: Please add a [mre]

Comment: Thanks for the note. Done.